# Sequentially continuous for punctured neighborhoods implies sequentially continuous?

Tags: general-topology

If we have that $f:X \to Y$ is sequentially continuous, then immediately for every sequence $x_n \to c$ with each $x_n \not = c$, we have $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. Does the converse hold?

The motivation for this question is that this is sometimes used in an analysis book I'm reading. In this context, and in the context of first-countable spaces, this converse holds (since the functions then can be proven to be continuous). If it does not hold in general, does it hold for Frechet-Urysohn spaces?

Comment: Yes the converse always holds. Please edit your post to include your attempts to prove it.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): again, please include your work.

Comment: You can check the Convergence of sequences in topological spaces and simply apply the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the latter condition holds.  Let $x_n$ be any sequence converging to $c$, and consider two cases:

1. all but finitely many of the $x_n$ are equal to $c$.
2. infinitely many of the $x_n$ are unequal to $c$.

In case 1, the conclusion $f(x_n) \to f(c)$ is trivial.

In case 2, consider the sequence $x_n'$ formed by deleting all occurrences of $c$ from $x_n$.  You have $f(x_n') \to f(c)$ by assumption.  Now show that $f(x_n) \to c$ as well.

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: As a side remark: it is useless to distinguish 2 cases. And the main part of your answer (the last sentence) can at best be considered as an encouragement to the OP to prove the conjecture on their own. Which imo they should do anyway.